# How to move files from one directory to another using an array

Tags: bash

I would like to move files I have from one directory to another using an array of keywords to find and categorize the files. I have some syntax issue with my find command and I'm not sure how to solve it. The error is:

```
./Process.sh: line 7: \*building\*: syntax error: 
        operand expected (error token is "\*building\*")
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a keyword=("*building*")
declare -a directory=("Building")

for i in "${keyword[@]}"
do
    echo find /run/media/_Incoming/ -type f -name "${keyword[$i]}" \
        -exec echo mv -t /run/media/"${directory[$i]}"/ {} +
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays use numbers such as 0, 1, 2 as indices. Your index `$i` is not a number, but an *element* of the array `keyword`. `${keyword[$i]}` expands to `${keyword[*building*]}` which is not a valid array entry.

You probably wanted to write:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a keyword=("*building*")
declare -a directory=("Building")

for i in "${!keyword[@]}"
do
    echo find /run/media/_Incoming/ -type f -name "${keyword[$i]}" \
        -exec echo mv -t /run/media/"${directory[$i]}"/ {} +
done
```

`${!keyword[@]}` (mind the `!` at the beginning) expands to all *indices* of array `keyword`. Because of the `echo` in front of `find` this will print the command

```
find /run/media/_Incoming/ -type f -name *building* -exec echo mv -t /run/media/Building/ {} +
```

Comment: Could be a good idea to suggest associative arrays: `declare -A ass=([Building]="*building*"); for i in "${!ass[@]}"; do ...`